# How to load a local video in React using webpack?

Tags: video, reactjs, webpack, loader, es6-module-loader

I can't seem to figure out how to get an html5 video to render in a react app from local files. Literally the only way I've been able to get this to work is like this:

```
<video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" controls />
```

**Here's what I've tried**

**1.** Including the path directly

```
<video src={require('path/to/file.mp4')} controls />
```

which returns an error

```
Module parse failed: /path/to/file.mp4 Line 1: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

---

**2.** Adding these loaders one at a time to the webpack config

```
{
  test: /\.(mp4)$/,
  loader: 'file'
  // loader: 'url-loader'
  // loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
  // loader: 'file-loader'
  // loader: 'file-loader?name=videos/[name].[ext]'
},
```

this spit out the following error in the browser

```
GET http://localhost:3000/530c2bf99dad0f857d46940b62b84946.mp4 404 (Not Found)
```

---

**3.** I tried adding a direct url to the file

```
<video src={require('http://localhost:3000/path/to/file.mp4')} controls />
```

but still errors:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'http://localhost:3000/path/to/file.mp4' in path/to/file.mp4
```

---

**4.** I tried adding the mp4 extension in my webpack config [like this person did](http://www.jordanpapaleo.com/blog/)

```
{
  test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.ico|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.ttf$|.mp4$/,
  loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
}
```

but no luck

---

**5.** I started implementing [webpack-isomorphic-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-isomorphic-tools#user-info-menu) but then I wasn't sure if this was the right direction so I paused on it. It seems like this guy got it working this way.  ([see file](https://github.com/bdefore/universal-redux/blob/master/config/webpack-isomorphic-tools.config.js))

---

I also noticed in the webpack documentation under [loader conventions](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loader-conventions.html) that `file-loader` will load video files.
[image: webpack documentation image]
Does this mean webpack won't load other video types such as `.mov, .vob, .avi, etc.`?

If you want to take a look at the code, [here's the repository](https://github.com/alex-cory/relay-test).

---

**Resources**

- [Webpack Docs: Loader Conventions](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loader-conventions.html)
- [Add a WebM and MP4 loader to the default Webpack config](https://github.com/bdefore/universal-redux/issues/68)
- [Loading mp4 video in to `video` tag w/ File loader](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/spectacle-boilerplate/issues/13)
- [Unable to load resources via file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/react-starter/issues/66)

Comment: "Does this mean webpack won't load other video types such as .mov, .vob, .avi, etc.?" --- it does not mean that: webpack does not care how you match filenames as soon as `test` passes.

Comment: I think your 'test' regex is wrong. Try `/\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|mp4)$/`.

Comment: @Dai what's wrong with it?

Comment: @zerkms Sorry, it just looked redundant and the last `.` was not escaped, but I don't think it is the origin of the problem, i.e. not wrong. What do you get in the `src` when using solution 4?

Comment: @Dai I'm not an OP :-) Indeed, the `.` must be escaped, but that could only lead to false-positives, that is not a problem at the moment.

Comment: try importing your file on top of the component instead of importing inside jsx. for ex: `import videoUrl from '/path/to/file.mp4' `and then inside jsx put `<video src={videoUrl}  />`.

Comment: yeah the `import` statement didn't work.  It still gave the **same error as solution 2**.

Comment: I was able to get it work doing both 1. and 2. together.  The only difference is that I did a `var x = require('path/to/video')`.  I also used the `name=videos/[name].[ext]`, may be related.  Also make sure you start and stop webpack if you're watching files.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem, my solution is:

It uses https://github.com/webpack/html-loader and https://github.com/webpack/url-loader:

The loaders configuration:

```
  loaders: [{
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: 'html-loader?attrs[]=video:src'
    }, {
      test: /\.mp4$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=video/mp4'
  }]
```

And in html:

A simple video tag, remeber webpack uses path referenced to the html file.

```
<video src="../../../assets/videos/cover1.mp4"></video>
```

This works for me.

References:
https://github.com/webpack/html-loader/issues/28

Comment: I suppose there is typo. should be `loader: 'url-loader?limit...`. Works for me this way

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old post, and the question is specifically about WebPack...

If you're using `Typescript` and a boilerplate such as `create-react-app`, and if you have your video on the static folder, then please check out this solution, of adding the type to `src/react-app-env.d.ts`, before ejecting your app:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6822

Comment: Just to add to this: if you are using VS Code, you'd have to restart your Typescript server as well. This is done by opening the Command Pallete (Ctrl + Shift + P) while in a .ts file then search for "restart TS server".