# Cannot load video files with Webpack 3 and File-Loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I'm loading assets with file-loader in Webpack3 and everything works well for common images types but when I try to load videos (MP4, MOV ...) it seems that it can't detect those. Here's the code to load assets in my webpack.config file:

```
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|svg|mp4|mov)$/,
        use: [
      {
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          outputPath: "assets/"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

And in my index.html file if I add this:

```
  <img src='assets/file.png' alt=''/>
```

Everything is ok but not if I try with a video tag like :

```
  <video width="320" height="240" controls id='video'>
    <source src="assets/video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may try the inline loader syntax; i.e.

```
import SomeVideo from '-!file-loader!../../../video2.mp4';
```

Or

```
require("file!../../../video2.mp4")
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It works but can't I automatize it with the webpack.config file ? For each video files instead of inlining the loader ?

Comment: I think you may use additional loaders, html-loader and url-loader. You can look at those two links 1) https://github.com/FormidableLabs/spectacle-boilerplate/issues/13   , and 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465127/how-to-load-a-local-video-in-react-using-webpack