# Webpack Build Not Rendering HTML5 Video

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, webpack.config.js

-- I have a HTML5 video that loads correctly while at localhost (dev environment).

**React component**

```
import HomeVideo from '../video/home.mp4';
const Home = () => (
  <div className="home-container">
    <div className='video-container'>
    </div>
    <video autoPlay loop>
      <source src={HomeVideo} type='video/mp4' />
      Your browser does not support the video tag.<a href="https://youtu.be/bgSMpRpObCg" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">Watch it here</a>
    </video>
  </div>
  </div>    
)
export default Home;
```

- The video loads correctly in DEV:

[image]

- As soon as I run `npm run build` my `webpack -p` process everything.

**Package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval-source-map --history-api-fallback --open",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
```

- With the production build I see the video in the console (however the `src=` shows the webpack build url) **Is that the problem?**

[image]

- The video does **not** load in the page though.

[image]

These is how my webpack.config.js is currently written:
ps: With or without the commented out lines the behavior is still the same. Works in dev and doesn't work after the build.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: `${__dirname}/src/index.js`,
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/build`,
    publicPath: '/build/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },


  module: {
    rules: [
      //{ test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader?attrs[]=video:src' },
      //{ test: /\.(mov|mp4)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=video/mp4' },
      {
        test: /\.(mov|mp4)$/, use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[path][name].[ext]'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', { loader: 'css-loader', options: { minimize: true } }],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(pdf|jpg|png|svg)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[path][name].[hash].[ext]",
          },
        },
      },
    ]
  },

  plugins: process.argv.indexOf('-p') === -1 ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      output: {
        comments: false,
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

**I don't know if it matters but this is being served at GitHub pages.

Comment: Are there errors in the console?

Comment: no errors at all

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465127/how-to-load-a-local-video-in-react-using-webpack ?

Comment: Have you import your video in main.js ?

Comment: Do you mean at the `Index.js` or `App.js`? I only imported the video from the component using it, which is `Home.js`...

Comment: please replace your source by <source src="./home.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Comment: Ok, so source it directly, without importing it first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166211/discussion-between-santosh-shinde-and-null-istrue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use following web pack config.(uncomment lines bellow, remove the limit from `/\.(mov|mp4)`

```
  { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader?attrs[]=video:src' },
  { test: /\.(mov|mp4)$/, loader: 'url-loader' },
```

Please check the similar type of question to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645675/webpack-3-locates-mp4-file-but-video-is-not-playable).

And also check the more about [url-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/) and [html-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader).

Hope this will help you !!

Comment: By passing the url directly it returns a 404. On react land, it only works if I import the file first.

Comment: I have added the webpack config please check it