# Cant import video file Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' ' (1:0) React.js Next.js

Tags: reactjs, video, module, next.js

hi im having the current problem, im trying to set a background with a video playing in loop, but at the moment of importing the mp4 video from the folder it gives me this error

```
error - ./videos/video.mp4
Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' ' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

this is how my component is beign created

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
 import Video from '../../videos/video.mp4';

const HeroContainer = styled.div`
background: #0c0c0c;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
padding: 0 30px;
height: 800px;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
`

const HeroBg = styled.div`
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
`
const VideoBg = styled.video`
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-o-object-fit: cover;
object-fit: cover;
background: #232a24;
`


export default function Hero() {
  return (
    <HeroContainer>
      <HeroBg>
        <VideoBg autoPlay loop muted src={Video} type='video/mp4'/> 

      </HeroBg>
    </HeroContainer>
  )
}
```

i really dunno what the problem could be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define loader to import `.mp4` file. This kind of error occurs with other file types, too. For example, I met this error when I tried to import `.gql` file. To solve the problem, you need to define loader for the specific file type.

If you are using webpack, this might help you.
[How to load a local video in React using webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36465127/how-to-load-a-local-video-in-react-using-webpack).

P.S. I personally dislike this kind of settings. I would like to say just give a url if possible.

Comment: i set it like this         <VideoBg autoPlay loop muted src="https://www.pexels.com/es-es/video/flores-ramo-de-flores-boda-peonia-4747643/" type='video/mp4'/>
but still doesnt show the video, any idea?

Comment: Well, the link you gave just show me the webpage. Seems like it's not a correct video url.

Comment: I found the current url https://player.vimeo.com/video/433317878, but still doesnt work lol

Comment: `<VideoBg.Source src={...url} type="video/mp4" />`

Comment: check here https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactjs-videobg?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=pmd_c4701227eb31cf8dac273c35abd3c1cb02d49991-1628809562-0-gqNtZGzNAs2jcnBszQkO